# How to increment IP address

Tags: ip, counter, increment

How to increment an IP address like this:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
...
0.0.0.255
0.0.1.0
0.0.1.1
...
0.0.255.0
0.1.0.0
0.1.0.1
...
0.1.0.255
0.1.1.0
...
0.1.255.0
0.1.255.1
0.1.255.2
...
0.2.0.0
...
```

My attempt gets me the first two tail nodes correctly, but anything more than that it gives the wrong output.

```
function increment_ip(input) {
  var iparray = input.concat()
  var output = []
  var i = iparray.length
  var inc = false

  while (i--) {
    var count = iparray[i]
    if (count < 255) {
      output.unshift(count)
      if (!inc) {
        iparray[i] = iparray[i] + 1
        inc = true
      }
    } else {
      iparray[i] = 0
      output.unshift(0)
      if (i - 1 > -1) {
        iparray[i - 1] = iparray[i - 1] + 1
      }
    }
  }

  return output
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modelling an IP address as an array, model it as a single number.

Each octet can be extracted by a mask and shift.

```
var ip = (input[0] << 24) | (input[1] << 16) | (input[2] << 8) | (input[3] << 0)
ip++
return [ip & 0xff000000 >> 24, ip & 0x00ff0000 >> 16, ip & 0x0000ff00 >>, ip & 0x000000ff]
```

Comment: What if you have more than 4 numbers such as similar to IP structure but 100 numbers `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.....100` Or wondering up to how many numbers this mask/shift pattern will work with.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','` of this code, `return` line :/

Comment: @Erikas no language tag on the question. This is valid Python

Answer (score 1):

Working Javascript function:

```
function incrementIP(inputIP) {
    let ip = (inputIP[0] << 24) | (inputIP[1] << 16) | (inputIP[2] << 8) | (inputIP[3] << 0);
    ip++;
    return [ip >> 24 & 0xff, ip >> 16 & 0xff, ip >> 8 & 0xff, ip >> 0 & 0xff];
}
```

Usage:

```
var myIP = [192, 168, 0, 1];
var myIncrementedIP = incrementIP(myIP);
console.log(myIncrementedIP);
```